# Bangla Unicode font breaks in PHP GD library

Tags: php, gd, fpdf, bengali

I have been working on a project where I am trying to create a image file from a form using PHP GD library. After creating the form I am converting it to an pdf file (with FPDF) and then download to local device. But the problem I am facing is that bengali font is not working properly. Is there any way I can resolve this issue? If GD library is not capable of doing this then is there any other way I can solve this problem? [Here is the image of what I am trying to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wbnA.jpg)

Marked words are coming from the form.

Here is the detail code. `<?php

// include_once 'database.php';
//$res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `wcertificate` WHERE status=0 limit 1");

```
    if (isset($_POST['insert'])){
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    //putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
    $font = $font = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\joshodol\warishan\Siyamrupali.ttf';

    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('warishan.jpg');
    $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 19, 21, 22); 
    $Date = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 510, 165, $color, $font, $_POST['Date']);
    $Sharok="";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 80, 165, $color, $font, $_POST['Sharok']);
    $name  = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 280, 295, $color, $font, $_POST['name']);
    $name1  = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 450, 295, $color, $font, $_POST['Fname']);
    $name2  = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 80, 320,  $color, $font, $_POST['Mname']);
    $Village  = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 250, 320, $color, $font, $_POST['Village']);
    $Post  = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 450, 320,  $color, $font, $_POST['Post']);
    $Serial1  = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 70, 587,  $color, $font, $_POST['Serial1']);
    $War1  = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 240, 587, $color, $font, $_POST['War1']);
    $War2  = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 435, 587,  $color, $font, $_POST['War2']);
    $Serial2  = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 70, 605,  $color, $font, $_POST['Serial2']);
    $War3  = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 240, 605, $color, $font, $_POST['War3']);
    $War4  = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 435, 605,  $color, $font, $_POST['War4']);
    $Serial3  = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 70, 623,  $color, $font, $_POST['Serial3']);
    $War5  = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 240, 623,  $color, $font, $_POST['War5']);
    $War6  = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 435, 623,  $color, $font, $_POST['War6']);
    $Serial4  = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 70, 641,  $color, $font, $_POST['Serial4']);
    $War7  = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 240, 641,  $color, $font, $_POST['War7']);
    $War8  = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 435, 641,  $color, $font, $_POST['War8']);
    $Serial5  = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 70, 659,  $color, $font, $_POST['Serial5']);
    $War9  = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 240, 659,  $color, $font, $_POST['War9']);
    $War10  = "";
    imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 435, 659,  $color, $font, $_POST['War10']);
    
    
        
        
    imagejpeg($image,'warishancertificate.jpg' );
    imagedestroy($image); 


    require('fpdf.php');
    $pdf = new FPDF(); 
    $pdf -> AddPage();
    $pdf -> Image ('warishancertificate.jpg', 0,0,200,200);
    $pdf -> Output("warishan.pdf", "F");
```

//Redirect

```
    header("Location: download.php");
}
```

?>
`

Comment: could you share more details, like the code you tried to check why are you getting that?

Comment: I have updated the post with the comment. Please read the Post for that.